# Is Java.NET platform independent?

Tags: java, .net, platform-independent

Java is the supported language by .NET.

Where is it used ? Is there any IDE available for programming with Java.NET ?

Isn't Java.NET a  platform independent ? Can we compile it using JVM ?

Comment: What are you referring to? What is Java.NET? Are you referring to the [java.net](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is **not** supported by .NET - C#, VB.NET and several other languages is.

Java, as well as a language, is a development platform entirely independent from .NET, although the underlying ideas are similar - one might indeed see .NET as Microsoft's answer to Java.

Comment: Have a look at J#...  Last seen in VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Sharp) J# is deprecated, the last Visual Studio version with J# was VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be really confused or someone has lead you to this confusion.

**Java is not supported by .NET and probably will never be.**

simple Java is Oracle (SUN) and .NET is Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop in c# and deploy on Java compatible hosts, you can do it using [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130).

Comment: pierre - just read the blurb on grasshopper. have you used this before or was it a google-ninja find?? just that it looks quite interesting and was wondering if it 'worked' with asp.net mvc 2.0

Comment: I read blog post about it few years ago. They (mainsoft) are also very active in the mono project. All I know is that the guy that wrote the article (Eric Sink from a company I don't remember the name) was very happy with it. He built a java version of a plugin in C#.

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll investigate further. cheers....